# List view performItemClick doesn't work

Tags: java, android, listview, background, onitemclick

I'm trying to call onItemClick manually when my fragment first starts up but it does not behave the way expected.It was called in the onCreateView() method as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        handler=new DBHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
        JustaMap=new HashMap<String,List<MediaMetadata>>();
        app = new Common();
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_playlist, container, false);
        musicProvider = new MusicProvider();
        SongTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        PlayList = new ArrayList<MediaMetadata>();
        musicProvider.buildSongFromDevice();
        SongList = (List<MediaMetadata>) musicProvider.getAllMusics();
        Iterator<MediaMetadata> iterator = SongList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
            SongTitles.add(iterator.next().getDescription().getTitle().toString());

        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.PlaylistName);
        button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit);
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SongTitles);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                MediaMetadata SongSelected = SongList.get(position);
                view.setSelected(true);
                if (view.getBackground() == null) {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.light_grey);
                    if (!Arrays.asList(PlayList).contains(SongSelected))
                        PlayList.add(SongSelected);
                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    PlayList.remove(SongSelected);
                }

            }
        });

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // createPlaylist();
            }
        });


        listView.performItemClick(
                listView.getAdapter().getView(2,null,null),2,listView.getAdapter().getItemId(2));

        return rootView;
    }
```

Basically,when the item is clicked,it's background is supposed to changed to grey but it remains white when the fragment starts up. I've used a debugger to step through and the onItemClick() is still called but the background does not change. However, if I perform the actual click on the list item,it actually works and the color changes as expected. It seems like the view's background got set back to null after calling performItemClick() but not when actual clicks occur. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track the position of the current selected element:

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        mSelectedItem = position;
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

And override the getView method of your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (position == mSelectedItem) {
        // set your color
    }

    return view;
}
```

**Or**

First you can create selector xml file like below in your drawable folder drawable/list_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#333333" />
        <padding android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" />
      </shape></item>
    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#222222" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

And then in your listview specify background as

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
```

Comment: Thanks the first method works! Any explanation on what is going on?

Comment: you were performing operation on view while it should be performed adapterview or specific (selected) child view of listview.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing,

```
listView.performItemClick(
                listView.getAdapter().getView(2,null,null),2,listView.getAdapter().getItemId(2));
```

with

```
listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
listView.setSelection(position);

 listView.performItemClick(
                listView.getAdapter().getView(2,null,null),2,2);
```

Additionally these 2 lines of code before your performItemClick create the illusion of having the list item selected. They also ensure the appropriate item is on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(your position, null, null).performClick();

Toast.makeText(this, ""+ listView.performItemClick(
                                         listView.getAdapter().getView(your position, null, null), your position, your position) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

this code worked for me